# validation in rhomobile application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rhomobile, rhodes

How can I perform validation in rhomobile application; the model is not accepting validation code. I have performed following steps:

1. Add rh-validatable and json to your build.yml
   extensions:

   - json
   - rh-validatable
2. installation:

   - cd rhodes_project_directory
   - git clone git://github.com/artemk/rh-validatable.git extensions/rh-validatable
3. require "validatable" in application.rb
4. include 'validatable' in model
5. Put validation code in model
   such as  validates_presence_of :name

Still I am getting error and can't figure out the error since I am running application in a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validation's features of metadata, like:

:validation => {
       :regexp = "^.+$",
       :validators = [:required, :number, :currency, :email, :phone],
       :min_len = 0,
       :max_len = 100,
       :min_value = 10,
       :max_value = 1000
    }

here is the link:

[Metadata validation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhosync/metadata#validation)